# Why would anyone use Heroku (security-related)?

Tags: security, ssl, heroku

Heroku seems great, but most non-trivial applications require authentication, and conventional authentication schemes require an SSL connection, and it's impossible to get `https://your_app_name.com` (you can only get `https://your_app_name.heroku.com`).

So if you're using Heroku, is it that:

1. You don't mind directing users to
   another domain (seems pretty
   bad)
2. You don't mind foregoing
   SSL for authentication (seems really
   bad)
3. Your app doesn't require authentication

Comment: -1 for making people choose YOUR answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is now a moot point. According to the documentation (http://docs.heroku.com/ssl, see http://addons.heroku.com/ for pricing), Heroku now allows custom domains to have SSL through their SSL Endpoint addon.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Heroku also just [announced support for SNI](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/5/18/announcing_heroku_free_ssl_beta_and_flexible_dyno_hours). This will allow them to attach SSL to any domain hosted on Heroku's service. It is still in beta but should get pushed to every one soon. Heroku continues to improve their security offerings.

Comment: Yup, this is fixed -- Heroku is amazing

Comment: you forgot to mention that ssl on heroku costs $100/month

Comment: There are several SSL options to choose from. $100/month is the most expensive while free is the least expensive. Each option has its pros and cons, but they all add SSL capability.

Comment: http://addons.heroku.com/ has the prices for SSL... today. That URL is subject to change.

Comment: Seems like the free option is gone? Is there a way to disable using https, because this website really isn't that important.

Comment: @wrongusername yeah, just turn it off. heroku addons:remove whatever the name of your SSL addon was.

Comment: Heroku makes everything Rails related simple. I agree. I'm a bit of a newbee. It seems that Network Solutions offers an SSL Certificate for $100/year and it would easily install on a site hosted by them. So, it's $100/year vs. heroku's endpoint $20/month or $240/year. GoDaddy's certificates are $70/year. I'm checking to see if NS and GD both have Rails 4 and Ruby 2, so if they do it seems like a good deal. I've only posted non-https sites on Heroku, so I really don't know what I'm getting into with GD and NS.

Answer (score 18):

Hey, it's James from Heroku.  The inability to use SSL with a custom domain is a problem shared by all multi-tenant platforms, due to a fundamental issue with the SSL protocol.  A solution is in the works, we'll post details as soon we've finalized the plan.

Comment: Is there an update to this? Default as of now is still $20/month ~ $240/month?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Twitter's OAuth for authentication on my apps (via [twitter-auth](http://github.com/mbleigh/twitter-auth)).

Generic OpenID or even Facebook Connect would work just as well, as each of these handle the sensitive bits of authentication on somebody else's server.

[Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) is an authentication gem that has has plugins for each of these methods.

However, SSL is now fully supported on Heroku, if you're willing to pay a price that reflects the difficulty in getting SSL to work in a multi-tenant environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom domain name in Heroku. This is not included in the free account though. Also Heroku makes it dead simple to deploy Ruby on Rails apps. Deploying a Ruby on Rails application on a cheap hosting provider that only gives you limited if any shell access can be a nightmare. Not mention Heroku's server already preconfigured to optimize Ruby on Rails code, likewise scaling up is just a matter of sliding a scale on the user interface.

Comment: So which one of the options in my question is it? I guess you don't care about SSL?

Answer (score 0):

With Heroku you can use custom domain names (in the free version too). 
Scaling is easy, very easy, and they are making it better and better (i'm testing memcached and work like a charm, delayed job, the backup system and the git integration are great too).
The only problem for me, as you wrote is the SSL...

Comment: How is the lack of SSL not a total show-stopper? Can you give an example of an application that doesn't require it?

Comment: OpenID doesn't require ssl on the client to be secure. So, you could use it.